# Parsing Entire AWS SQS Record using GSON

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, parsing, gson, amazon-sqs

I have been trying unsuccessfully now to parse this message. Using the AWS Simple Queue Service API, I follow instructions and do the following...

```
for(Message m : Messages){
    System.out.println(m.getBody());
}
```

This returns a JSON string in this structure:

```
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "EventSource": "",
            "EventVersion": "",
            "EventSubscriptionArn": "",
            "Sns": {
                "Type": "",
                "MessageId": "",
                "TopicArn": "",
                "Subject": null,
                "Message": ""                
                "Timestamp": "",
                "SignatureVersion": "",
                "Signature": "”
                "SigningCertUrl": "",
                "UnsubscribeUrl": "",
                "MessageAttributes": {}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have been trying to parse this entire thing to a Java Object using GSON so that I can extract the "Message" parameter (which also contains JSON) and then use GSON to parse that (done and works when I just pass that text directly).

These are the classes I set up, but this will not work -- Each one has public getters and setters.....

Records Class:

```
public class Records {

    public ArrayList<ExceptionMessages> exceptionMessages = new ArrayList<ExceptionMessages>();

    public ArrayList<ExceptionMessages> getExceptionMessages() {
        return exceptionMessages;
    }

    public void setExceptionMessages(ArrayList<ExceptionMessages> exceptionMessages) {
        this.exceptionMessages = exceptionMessages;
    }
```

Message Class:

```
public class ExceptionMessages {

    public String EventSource;
    public String EventVersion;
    public String EventSubscriptionArn;
    public Sns messageJSON;     
}
```

Sns Class (where the message is stored):

```
public class Sns {

    public String Type;
    public String MessageId;
    public String TopicArn;
    public String Subject;
    public String Message;
    public String Timestamp;
    public String SignatureVersion;
    public String Signature;
    public String SigningCertUrl;
    public String UnsubscribeUrl;
    public String MessageAttributes;
}
```

I get a null pointer exception when trying to `.get(0)` of the ArrayList so it's empty and parsing did not take place.

Here is how I'm calling it...

I'm sending `m.getBody()` to a parsing method and attempting to parse like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Records record = new Records();
gson.fromJson(JSONString.replaceAll("\\s+", ""), Records.class);
```

Comment: Hint: does the phrase `exceptionMessages` ever occur in your JSON? And where is the field named `Records` in your code?

Comment: And what is up with `messageJSON` vs `Sns` (which occurs in the JSON)? You seem to understand that you should name the fields according to the names in the JSON but then midway through forget about it and invent new names.

Comment: So, the Exception Class.. it looks like Records is an Array of ojbects.. I wasn't sure what to call the object class (which is why I just called it Exception Class).. messageJSON is the name for the Sns object within the Record Class. It's a nested object.. correct? I have updated the post to show the actual Gson call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure should be

```
class RecordContainer {
    ArrayList<Record> Records;
}

class Record {
    public String EventSource;
    public String EventVersion;
    public String EventSubscriptionArn;
    public Sns Sns;     
}

class Sns {
    public String Type;
    public String MessageId;
    public String TopicArn;
    public String Subject;
    public String Message;
    public String Timestamp;
    public String SignatureVersion;
    public String Signature;
    public String SigningCertUrl;
    public String UnsubscribeUrl;
    public MessageAttributes MessageAttributes;
}
```

Comment: Of course!!! A Records class to hold a Record... I don't know why I didn't see this.  I have blinders on this morning. I really appreciate your help. This has been driving me absolutely insane!

Comment: For the `MessageAttributes` why is a `MessageAttributes` type defined here?